# HashMap not matching the value

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a hashmap of buttons to their corresponding points in a matrix. For example in a 3X3 matrix, btn0 is at (0,0) and so on. The point is a class with 2 int variables for coordinates. My Hashmap is like below:

```
public final static HashMap<Button, Point> buttonPoint = new HashMap<Button, Point>();
buttonPoint.put(btn0, new Point(0,0));
buttonPoint.put(btn1, new Point(0,1));
buttonPoint.put(btn2, new Point(0,2));
buttonPoint.put(btn3, new Point(1,0));
...
```

I perform few calculations and come up with a point say (1,0). Now I want to get the button from those coordinates. I do the following:

```
Button selectedButton = null;
    for(java.util.Map.Entry<Button, Point> entry : buttonPoint.entrySet()){
    if(Objects.equals(selectedPoint, entry.getValue())){
        selectedButton=entry.getKey();
    }
    }
```

But the selectedButton is still null. I debugged the code and I see that the values are equal at some point in iteration, but still the if condition never becomes true. Is there anything I am missing about Hashmaps ? Or is there any other way of doing it ? Any link or direction towards a solution will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a button from coordinates, using a `Map<Button, Point>` is not a good solution. You should use a `Map<Point, Button>` instead. That way, all you need to get the button at a given point is

```
Button b = map.get(point);
```

and this operation operates in constant time.

In both cases, you need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Point`. Otherwise a point will never be equal to any other point.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o.getClass() != Point.class) {
        return false;
    }
    Point other = (Point) o;
    return other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Jus out of curiosity, what difference does it make when both key and value are unique ?

Comment: See my answer. Think of a map as a dictionary. Is it faster to find the definition of a given word, or is it faster to get a word given its definition?

Comment: @JB Nizet it is weird but this code print yes but these are differen objects.i don't override equal method:
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
        Point p2 = new Point(0, 0);
       
        if(Objects.equals(p, p2)){
            System.out.println("yes");   
        }

Comment: @Serkhan No way. You're probably using java.awt.Point, which does override equals() and hashCode().

Comment: Because actual implemention of equals on java.awt.Point does the same : 
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Point) {
            Point pt = (Point)obj;
            return (x == pt.x) && (y == pt.y);
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

Comment: @JBNizet, Yes I understand that a hashmap as a dictionary. There is a part of code where I find the coordinates using the button using the same HashMap. That was the reason I used the Map with Button as key. Will it work if I jus implement the override methods ?

Comment: Yes, because Objects.equals() will now return true for two points with the same coordinates. But it would be faster to use a BiMap, or two Maps, or at least to break out of the loop once you've found the button

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !! It worked. I decided to go with the mentioned Hashmap since there will be only 9 values always. Anyways I added a break.

Answer (score 1):

```
 HashMap<Button, Point> buttonPoint = new HashMap<>();

 Collection<Point> values = buttonPoint.values();

 for(Point p: values){
    if(p.x == selectedPoint.x && p.y== selectedPoint.y){
       //code
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if i suggest to look at @JB Nizet answer as its a better approch, to fix your issue you can change

```
Button selectedButton = null;
for(java.util.Map.Entry<Button, Point> entry : buttonPoint.entrySet()){
    if(Objects.equals(selectedPoint, entry.getValue())){
        selectedButton=entry.getKey();
    }
}
```

by

```
Button selectedButton = null;
for(java.util.Map.Entry<Button, Point> entry : buttonPoint.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue().equals(selectedPoint)){
        selectedButton=entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this was my 1st approach. I then googled if there are any other ways to do this and I got the approach I had put in my question. This doesn't work either.

Comment: The only difference between those two is how `null` values are treated.  In matter of fact, the second one could be considered a poorer solution because it will throw a `NullPointerException` if a `null` value is encountered.

Comment: So it may come from the selectedPoint. Can you show us how its setted ? and what is it's value